# Is it possible to replicate the effects of disabling CSSOM View Scroll Coordinates flag in chrome using css code?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, ag-grid

I want to know what disabling `CSSOM View Scroll Coordinates` flag in `chrome://flags` does and how can i replicate this behavior using code in my `ReactJS` app.

**Additional information :**
It seems after Chrome 85 update, `ag-grid` RTL support breaks and the grid is not able to scroll the content and sometimes the cells becomes white, i had to dig very deep into the past questions and try a lot of far fetched solutions to find what i have.
I found out that `disabling` `CSSOM View Scroll Coordinates` in `chrome://flags` will fix the bug!~ but the problem is i don't want to force my users and teach them to do this just so my app works, so i thought what ever **disabling** `CSSOM View Scroll Coordinates` does, maybe i can replicate it using css code or some other code

I have already reported this issue in `ag-grid`'s `git-hub` but i'm still waiting for them to offer a solution in the mean time if i can get this to work only using code, it would be great as i have a lot of users which are not able to use my app just because of this simple bug ..
Thank you.

Comment: With version 86, disabling CSSOM View Scroll Coordinates doesn't workaround the problem anymore

Comment: @Cesar yes.., i had to upgrade to the new ag-grid version in which they fixed the problem, of course i should mention for some reason, in some of the clients Chrome, the problem still remained!, i had to uninstall the whole chrome and install it again for them to fix the problem, it seems somehow chrome would cache something which would made the ag-grid update to not work.